# dplyr pass function name to summarize

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function that uses dplyr to summarize a variable.  I want to be able to pass the name of the summary function as a parameter.  The approach below works (using match.fun).  I was wondering if there is a better/simpler approach?

```
exampleFunction <- function(df, var, function_name, ...){
var <- enquo(var)

apply_some_function <-function(data, function_name, ...){
   FUN <- match.fun(function_name)
   FUN(data,...)
}

results <- df %>%
   summarize (result=apply_some_function(!!var, function_name,...))
}
exampleFunction(iris, Sepal.Width, "mean")
exampleFunction(iris, Sepal.Width, "min")
```

Comment: You can use `get`

Comment: Why pass the name as a string, instead of passing the actual function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually no need to pass a function by its name in R -- since functions are first-class(ish), you can almost always just pass the function itself!

For example:

```
library(dplyr)

# data to illustrate
iris <- iris[1:10, ]
iris$Sepal.Length[1:3] <- NA

# the custom summary function 
custom_summary <- function(df, var, summary_func, ...){
  var <- enquo(var)
  df %>% summarize(res = summary_func(!!var, ...))
}

# check that we can pass params to `summary_func` via `...`:
custom_summary(iris, var=Sepal.Length, summary_func=mean)
custom_summary(iris, var=Sepal.Length, summary_func=mean, na.rm=TRUE)

# double-check result against same thing in global env: 
iris %>% summarize(res = mean(Sepal.Length))
iris %>% summarize(res = mean(Sepal.Length, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Note that while passing column names to functions is annoying and complicated in `dplyr::`, passing functions as parameters to other functions is a perfectly natural thing to do in R. Especially when combined with the `magrittr::` pipe, this enables super compact summaries. Just one example:

```
funcs <- c(mean=mean, mdn=median, lu=function(x) length(unique(x)))
cols <- c("Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")

funcs %>% sapply(function(f) iris[, cols] %>% sapply(f))
##                  mean  mdn lu
## Petal.Length 3.758000 4.35 43
## Petal.Width  1.199333 1.30 22
## Sepal.Length 5.843333 5.80 35
## Sepal.Width  3.057333 3.00 23
```

Comment: Why “…ish”? There’s pretty much no distinction between functions and other values in R (functions carry some special attributes — their defining environment — but that’s not a restriction).

Comment: Well I don't think "first-class" has a universally accepted mathematical definition, but I would say that certain restrictions justify the "-ish" (e.g. you can store them in a list but not an atomic vector or a data frame). I would say that distant cousins of R like Haskell have first-class functions without the "-ish." That's how I think about it at least, probably no platonic fact of this matter!

Comment: There are tons of other things that you can’t store in vectors & DFs either; at least: lists, pair lists, and environments (but those are really not first class). Don’t you consider lists first-class citizens in R …?

Comment: hmmm yeah idk, again i think the terminology is not super precise here. depends on the notion of "first class" one has in mind i suppose. my mental model of R definitely treats functions like any other values, but that is more of an intuitive conception than a claim!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarize_at`

```
exampleFunction2 <- function(df, var, function_name, ...){
  var <- enquo(var)
  results <- df %>%
    summarize_at(vars(!!var), .funs = function_name,...) %>%
    setNames("result")
}
identical(exampleFunction2(iris, Sepal.Width, "mean"), 
          exampleFunction(iris, Sepal.Width, "mean"))
# [1] TRUE
```